# Can I use windows icons in my .Net application

Tags: windows, icons, license, copy-protection, copyright

I want to use Icons that appear on certain windows and dialog boxes in the Windows OS such is the Information bubble icon [Here](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcS_CXspQX_4iUmrp9xMmML3xZYs7Kbaojubtg&usqp=CAU) in my application.
My application will be distributed free of charge under a closed source software license. So can I use the windows icons in my closed source free application?

Note: My application is a .net application and  is developed in Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing advice is off-topic on Super User.